# Problem creating and writing a subdirectory in Swift 5

Tags: swift, document

I'm having a problem trying to write a text file to a subdirectory of my Documents folder.

My code is as follows:

```
 @objc func makeFileButtonTapped() {
        print(#function)
        
        let tempName = "test"
        
    var tempRecurrance: String = ""
          
          switch recurrentInt {
          case 0:
              tempRecurrance = "Never"
              
          case 1:
              tempRecurrance = "Sometimes"
              
          case 2:
              tempRecurrance = "Often"
              
          default:
               tempRecurrance = "Unknown"
          }
          
          
          fileName = tempName + ".txt"
          
          let tempTitle: String = "\n\Title: " + titleString + "\n\n"
          let tempDate: String = "Date: " + dateString + "\n\n"
          let tempRecurring: String = "Recurs: " + tempRecurrance + "\n\n\n\n"
        
          
          myDocument = ""
          myDocument.append(tempTitle)
          myDocument.append(tempDate)
          myDocument.append(tempRecurring)
        
    
        saveToDirectory()
    }



func saveToDirectory(){
     print(#function)
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
       
        //  Create subdirectory
        do {
            
        let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
         let myAppDirectoryURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("MySubDirectory")
        
        
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: myAppDirectoryURL.path) {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: myAppDirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            print("New directory created.")
        
            //print("dictionary already exists.")
    }
        //  Create document
         let documentURL = myAppDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent (fileName)
            
            try myDocument.write(to: documentURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)

            print("documentURL =", documentURL.path)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
```

I'm getting a console message that the directory `{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}`.

Comment: Is this MacOS or iOS?    Where in your code is the error being reported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the check if the file already exists, `if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: myAppDirectoryURL.path)` since the `createDirectory` call will not generate an error if the directory already exist when you have `withIntermediateDirectories` set to true.

You used some properties that weren't part of the question, so here is my test version of your function for completeness:

```
func saveToDirectory(_ fileName: String, text: String) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    do {
        let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let myAppDirectoryURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("MySubDirectory")
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: myAppDirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        let documentURL = myAppDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent (fileName)
        try text.write(to: documentURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```