# Auto create directory when writing a file to a directory that does not exist

Tags: swift, xcode, file-manager

I am using File Manager to write files to the users documents directory. Every file is downloaded to a users device via a URL and then I create a local URL by doing the following:

```
extension URL {
    func getLocalUrl() -> URL {
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.getDocumentsDirectory()
        let filePath = pathComponents.dropFirst().joined(separator: "-")
        return directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(filePath)
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, when I try to create a local URL by using slashes instead of dashes via the following:

```
extension URL {
    func getLocalUrl() -> URL {
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.getDocumentsDirectory()
        let filePath = pathComponents.dropFirst().joined(separator: "/")
        return directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(filePath)
    }
}
```

I get the following error when this code runs:

```
func save(url: URL, fileUrl: URL) {
    do {
        // fileUrl is a url in the temporary directory from a URLSession.downloadTask
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileUrl, to: url.getLocalUrl())
    } catch {
        print("download.service.write.error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

> CFNetworkDownload_sKaBto.tmp” couldn’t be moved to “user-data” because either the former doesn’t exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn’t exist."

As you can see the error is because I am trying to write to a directory that does not exist. Is there a way to auto create the directory if it does not exist?

Comment: Yes there is, `createDirectory(at:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:)` Here is a somewhat related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576739/problem-creating-and-writing-a-subdirectory-in-swift-5/69576948#69576948)

Comment: I gotcha - thanks! So pretty much what I would have to do is remove the last path component, and create the directory and then write a file to that directory.

Comment: And I would not have to worry about creating the directory multiple times or overriding anything